# How to show status bar on LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

how to show status bar on LibGDX?
I'am tried this code:

```
config.hideStatusBar = false;
```

and this:

```
<resources>

<style name="GdxTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```

But, it isn't work.
Please, help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config.hideStatusBar = false;`  // by default this value is false

Try this code in your `AndroidLauncher` class.

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
layout.addView(initializeForView(new Splash(), config));
setContentView(layout);
```

Below of the statement not executed When you call `initializeForView` instead of `initialize`.

```
try {
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log("AndroidApplication", "Content already displayed, cannot request FEATURE_NO_TITLE", ex);
    }
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(graphics.getView(), createLayoutParams());
```

**One more thing** when you click on `GdxTheme` in `AndoridManifest.xml` file then it show multiple implementations, one is inside this `android/res/values/styles.xml` and another is 
`/Users/User_name/.android/build-cache/ea795811fd85c01c9ffd4c12717047945b0f2585/output/res/values-v11/values-v11.xml`

When I edit `android/res/values/styles.xml` file, nothing happen.

```
<resources>
    <style name="GdxTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style> 
</resources>
```

then I make same change in

```
/Users/User_name/.android/build-cache/ea795811fd85c01c9ffd4c12717047945b0f2585/output/res/values-v11/values-v11.xml
```

After that it works.

I have tried to clean buildCache

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

and clean Project too but changes not reflect from my project to cache `.xml` file.